# Проблема запуска приложения на устройстве API level 15 android

Tags: android, android-layout

При запуске приложения на устройстве API level 15 падает с такими вот сообщениями

```
binary XML file line #24: You must supply a layout_height attribute.

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x1
```

Обратил внимание только сейчас, т.к.  до этого запускал на устройствах api > 16 (на эмуляторе и реальных устройствах - все было ок) 
Первый элемент на котором приложение падает.

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_start_background"
        android:text="Начать"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        />
```

Какой код еще выложить - не знаю, что нужно говорите  -  я добавлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [гуглу](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18844713/3212712) проблема может быть в стилях. Точнее - в отсутствии переопределения к-л аттрибута в дефолтной теме (точнее в теме для проблемного уровня `API` или конкретного девайса с конкретными значениями плотности пикселей или высоты/ширины экрана).

Попробуйте убрать, например, вот это:

```
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
```

из этого элемента разметки.

В данном случае отсутствовали значения для элемента которые лежат в папках

```
values-sw360dp/dimens.xml
values-sw480dp/dimens.xml
values-sw600dp/dimens.xml
```

но так как устройство имело  sw350dp - оно брало значения с дефолтного файла `values/dimens.xml` в  котором данное значение отсутствовало. Проблема была решена добавлением  нужного значения в файл `values/dimens.xml`

Answer (score 3):

Обнаружил ошибку. Проблема была не в API, а в размере экрана.

Мои значения лежали в папках:

```
values-sw360dp/dimens.xml
values-sw480dp/dimens.xml
values-sw600dp/dimens.xml
```

Но устройство на котором я запускал приложение не подпадало ни под одну категорию и брало дефолтные значения с `values/dimens.xml`. Но атрибут высоты кнопки в этом файле отсутствовал. Добавив нужное значения в файл `values/dimens.xml` - все заработало!

Comment: В общих чертах я именно это имел в виду  своём ответе. И ссылка в нём как раз на этот случай указывает)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, меня это и натолкнуло на эту мысль)

Comment: Если вам не лень, то вы можете инфу из своего ответа перенести в мой через правку)

Answer (score 2):

Случаем, у вас не

```
<RelativeLayout
...
android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"/>
```

? Если да, то проблема в нем http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html#ALIGN_PARENT_END

Comment: только         android:layout_alignParentStart="true"